# Not able to connect SQL Server with GC Data Fusion

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-data-fusion

I have an SQL Server instance running locally where I have several tables, my purpose is to first fetch one of the tables with Data Fusion using the SQL Server Connection following the steps provided in [GC docs](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/reading-from-sqlserver).

However, when it's time to test-connect the Data Fusion connection through the Wrangler tab option I get this error on repeat:

[image: Connection Configuration]

I've been searching the issue for a while. I have enabled TCP/IP protocol in SQL Server Configuration Manager, set all TCP ports to default 1433 leaving all dynamic TCP ports blank, got SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) and SQL Server Browser running, checked that 127.0.0.1:1433 is active through command `telnet 127.0.0.1 1433` but still unable to connect, dropped windows firewall also, still not able.

Watched several videos/posts of people connecting with MySQL local instances without issues but none specifically to SQL Server. I created a login in SQL Server locally just for this purpose (User4Beam) to access through SQL Server login, I think that somehow Data Fusion detects the local instance of SQL Server since "Connection is refused", I also find interesting that jdbc connection string doesn't show password as a key argument, but I'm clueless about what else to try and I don't want to speculate about things I don't know.

JDBC Driver (sqlserver9.4-jre8) was downloaded and deployed without any issue (tried also with Driver sqlserver12.2 but didn't have luck so I don't think that this is causing the issue), SQL Server local version is 19.0.2.

Also noticed this step in the documentation

[image: Steps in GC]

Since I couldn't find any SQL Server plugin in the Hub tab of Data Fusion I wonder if this is causing the issue.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!.

Comment: There is no SQL Server v19.0.2, that sounds like your SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) version. SQL Server 2022 is currently running through the v16 series.

Comment: Isn't Cloud Data Fusion running on computers inside Google Cloud? How will it be connecting to 127.0.0.1 (aka. localhost) on your own computer?

Comment: Yes sorry, v19.0.2 is SSMS's version and the local instance is SQL Server 2022 and Yes, Data Fusion runs on computers inside GC, the main issue is that I don't know how to connect it to my local instance, what do I have to configure in GC to do that?

Comment: I think the simple answer is, you can't. Maybe you can luck out if you find your external ip(showmyip) and there's nothing blocking it on the way through to port 1433 (unlikely). The idea is perhaps to use some publish sql server like azure or google's own

Comment: Neither of your screenshots should be an image, the information on them can be much better communicated by adding the actual text to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar public [article](https://medium.com/cdapio/sql-server-data-movement-with-cdap-ebe408604386) that address your inquiry.